# Oracle Reverse Engineer ERD for Mac

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, reverse-engineering, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have a large database, over 100 tables, and I would like to reverse-engineer it into an ERD. I would like to do this automatically. OracleDataModeler works fine for me but seems to only let me select one table at a time. With my large database, I want to find a tool that will apply the ERD to the entire database, at once.

However, my employer has us using only MacOs (I'm on Monterey) and I can't find anything that will work for me. It doesn't have to be a free tool, I'm willing to pay for it, but all tools that I find seem to be only for Windows systems.

As a side tip, I had used RedGate software to do this with SQLServer databases and it is really easy to use. It worked great. If I could find something like that, it would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: In the datamodeler, when you get to the tables list, you have 2 icons near the filter field (bottom of the window) one of them lets you 'select all'. Click on it when you get to the screen, don't select any line before

Answer (score 1):

> OracleDataModeler works fine for me but seems to only let me select
> one table at a time.

No...use the Import wizard, point to your connection, select your schema/objects, and Voila.

[Step By Steps](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/10/importing-your-data-dictionary-to-a-new-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler-design/)

[image]

Connect to your datbase, pick your schemas and object types, and then...pick your objects...Click the 'Select All' button to grab everything.

[image]

Let it work it's magic..it may take awhile depending on how many objects you selected.

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee and the product manager for SQL Developer / Data Modeler.

Comment: Thanks! I was in the wrong screen, it turns out. I really appreciate your help and am also glad I don't have to go to my boss to ask to buy additional software.  :-)

Comment: You bet @Geo - good luck on your project!